# Why doesn't Vesper give Bond the additional $5M?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, casino-royale

After Bond loses the first $10M in *Casino Royale* he asks Vesper for the additional buy-in, saying he can win, yet gets rejected by Vesper nonetheless.

Isn't it a plot hole here? Vesper had one goal that is getting all the money so she can save his boyfriend. She was going to steal the money from Bond (which she eventually tried to) and as it turns out, she was ready to die for saving him.

If that is the case why didn't she give him the extra buy-in money? Worst would be Bond failing to win and losing all the money. That wouldn't make a difference to Vesper. If she was going all-out, sacrificing everything, then shouldn't she have given the money to Bond?

Comment: My guess is that at a pinch, she thought she had a chance of getting away with the $5M. I can't find anything that justifies that, it's just what I'd do in her place.

Comment: @Richard Yeah but it is a rather big gap between $5M and $115M

Comment: According to the UK govt, [most victims are released for less than £3M](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/382438/CTS_Bill_-_Factsheet_9_-_Kidnap_and_Ransom.pdf) so she'd have *some* leverage even if she couldn't get her mitts on the full $115M

Answer (score 13):

Vesper's initial mission from the organization (later found out to be Quantum) was not to steal the money, but to sabotage Bond.

The Organization 'kidnapped' Vesper's boyfriend in order to blackmail her in exchange for his life, for which her mission was to ruin Bond's chances of winning.

This is because Quantum *want* Le Chiffre to win. They were the ones who risked their reputation with the African warlord at the beginning of the movie to recommend Le Chiffre to be their investor.

Le Chiffre puts on the poker game in order to win *their* money back, not Quantum's. So they plant Vesper in order to make sure Bond doesn't win, which is why it is *she* who tells Le Chiffre that Bond has discovered his tell, and not Matthis as Bond later suspected, and this causes him to lose all of his money, and takes him out of the game as Vesper will not give him any further money.

Had things gone to plan and Felix and the CIA not intervened, Le Chiffre would likely have won. However when he loses he kidnaps Vesper and tortures Bond in order to get the $115 million.

When Mr. White from Quantum intervenes in the torture, it is explained by M near the end of the film that Vesper made a *further* deal at that time. If Mr. White spared Bond, she would retrieve the password for the account from him and then steal the money.

This was obviously a lot more risky than simply hindering Bond's chances of winning, hence why the initial plan was simply for Le Chiffre to win and keep the money, allowing him to pay back the warlord.

Comment: This certainly seems plausible but can you back it up (with quotes and references)?